# Проблема с php fpm

Tags: php, phalcon, php-fpm

Вот часть кода

```
  foreach ($page->items as $rec) {
        $temp = array();

        $rec->image = $rec->Photos[0];
        foreach ($rec->Structure as $row) {     
            foreach ($row->Ingredients as $key => $item) {          
                $item->mer = $row->Units[$key]->name;
                $item->shortcut = $row->Units[$key]->shortcut;
                $item->count = $row->count;
                $temp[] = $item;        
            }
        }       
        $rec->ingredients = array('test'=>'test2');

    }
```

В обычном php без проблем в цикле по объекту можно объявить новое свойство объекта и дать ему любой тип но тут не получается. 
В строке
`$rec->ingredients = array('test'=>'test2');`

Но вот если я буду писать так то заработает

```
$rec->ingredients  = 'test';
```

или

```
$rec->ingredients  = json_encode(array('test'=>'test2'));
```

Поясните в чем проблема, на apache и обычном php  все время писал работало на nginx и php fpm  первый раз пишу

Если пушу так то работает:

```
$rec->ing = '';     
$rec->ing =  [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
```

То есть объявляю как строку потом перекручиваю на массив

Comment: php везде работает одинаково. И в fpm режиме и как модуль апача. Ваша проблема в чем-то другом.

Comment: @u_mulder на локальном сервере работает так, на vps не пашет, разница только в серверах =(  Не понимаю почему массивы не присваиваются а вот со строками все норм

Comment: Так на серверах у вас и версии php скорее всего отличаются. Смотрите логи ошибок, есть какая-то ошибка с этим, точно уже не помню какая именно. Вам посмотреть логи быстрее будет

Comment: Дело в том что скрипт работает просто в ответе нет этого массива, выдает json  просто без него, ничего не отваливается, показ ошибок включен display_errors = On, error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT